# Netbeans additional unneeded code hints

Tags: javascript, netbeans

When i'm in Netbeans 8.0, developing JavaScript and i'm on a line of code like this:

```
var sum = (example / anotherExample)
```

And i type a dot after that so it becomes this:

```
var sum = (example / anotherExample).
```

And press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> i get a lists of some code hints with the description of:

> JS Platform

Like this:

[image]

Whenever I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for the second time while im on that interface, it gives me the list with all possible code hints for that line of code.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

This `CTRL+Space` is a shortcut key to get hint about all the fields,methods,etc. defined for the attribute which you have used!

Taken from Netbeans Documentations,

> When the user clicks **Ctrl-Space**, or an alternative key combination
>   defined by the user, our code completion entries should appear. This
>   is the **COMPLETION_QUERY_TYPE**. Alternative query types exist, such as
>   DOCUMENTATION_QUERY_TYPE and TOOLTIP_QUERY_TYPE.

It helps completion of your code in a quick way without needing you to put efforts by typing manually the complete statement!

So,it's a much needed feature in IDE's and is a boon for developers. Also,if you have the documentation installed in your NetBeans Path or embedded in your NetBeans IDE,it will show the complete description of those parameters(fields,methods,etc) in the space.That's an extra plus point.

**Happy,CHEERS!**

Comment: Thanks for this, but i wonder why it still gives me the first screen then with all the unnessacary code hints with the `JS Platform` on the right?

Comment: Read the answer with some patience! It's a beautiful feature of ide,not like a crap. Read it line by line

Comment: @Bas-Would you mind accepting my answer as I have provided everything.If you have further doubt,PLEASE comment.Answers satisfying and exact must be accepted on StackOverflow.Please don't get irritated,but,I really need those points.

Comment: Actually, i asked why the additional unneeded code hints are showen before? But i voted your answer up because you explained the whole thing to me.

Comment: It's for the benefit/sake of programmer so that professionals don't need to type the whole sentence.They can simply double click and the statement will be complete!

Comment: Yeah i know, but what i'm trying to say is that there first comes up a list with some code hints i dont really need... So why doesnt it display the whole list in one go?

Comment: @Bas-Another point which comes here is that what if someone is forgetting all the methods of a class,say in `html`,if you don't know which attributes are defuined for a tag,it'll help by enlisting the whole of attributes in a quick view.Ain't it powerful,best and innovative feature!

Comment: @Bas-It helps to decide as to how to use that piece of code.
Say,in html,you have `<img>` tag and you don't know what it is for.It gives a short view as to what it's use is and what its attributes are.I hope it solves your query,BUT,keep asking until you're clear.

Comment: @Bas-Now,are you satisfied to accept my answer OR is there any further doubt!Please don't consider it as an irritation.I just really need those reputations as I have given the correct solution!

Comment: You're giving the same explaination every time.. I know its for people who dont know all code tags, but i ment: Why does the first screen come up, with all the unnessacary code hints, with the description of `JS Platform`. No one needs those, so i have to press ctrl space again?